# WTForm GAE model_field doesn't render fields in Jinja2 template

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, wtforms

I get get my form to display using the WTForm model_form on Google App Engine.  I expect to see the fields displayed when I visit /admin/newpost

**My Model**

```
class BlogPost(db.Model):
    #The URL path to the blog post. Posts have a path if they are published.
    path = db.StringProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
    body = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    published = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

**My PostHandler**

```
class PostHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

@webapp2.cached_property
def jinja2(self):
    return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

def render_to_response(
    self,
    template_name,
    template_vals=None,
    theme=None
    ):
    template_name = "admin/%s" % template_name
    self.response.out.write(render_template(
        template_name, template_vals, theme))

def render_form(self, form):
    self.render_to_response("edit.html", {'form': form()})

def get(self):
    form = model_form(BlogPost)
    self.render_form(form)
```

**Edit.html Template That Does Not Work**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}New Post{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  <form method="post" action="">
    <table>
      {{form}}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

With this template I see html with a form button.  The problem is none of the model fields get displayed.  To get my fields to display I have to do this...

**Edit.html Template That Works**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Testing New Post Template{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  <form method="post" action="">
    <table>

<div>{{ form.title.label }}: {{ form.title(class="css_class") }}</div>
{% if form.title.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.name.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}

<div>{{ form.body.label }}: {{ form.body() }}</div>
{% if form.body.errors %}
        <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.body.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}

    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

In short, how to I get the first version to display my model fields in the form?

Answer (score 1):

You can either subclass WTForms.Form to provide a [`__html__`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Markup) method that iterates over all of the sub-fields and returns them:

```
class CustomForm(Form):
    def __html__(self):
        fields = [u"%s %s" % (field.label, field) for field in self.fields]
        return Markup(u"".join(fields))
```

Or you can create a macro in Jinja to render the form (I've got an example [here](https://github.com/svieira/Budget-Manager/blob/master/app/templates/helpers/form_helpers.html), if you want to see one).